# Material UI DataGrid params only passing last value in the table

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, datagrid

I have a Data Grid table of users, the last column of the table is meant to be a sub-menu of options that each open up a modal. However, when I try to pass the data of a given row to a modal, it will only pass the final row of the data set (i.e. if I have 10 users, it passes rowId:10).

```
export default function Users() {
  const [userData, setUserData] = React.useState([]);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    let apiClient = new APIClient();
    apiClient.getUser().then((response) => {
        setUserData(response);
        console.log(response);
    });
  }, []);
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState<null | HTMLElement>(null);

  const [showEditModal, setShowEditModal] = React.useState<boolean>(false);
  const [showDeleteModal, setShowDeleteModal] = React.useState<boolean>(false);
  //for each modal

    const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
    const moreOptions = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
      setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
      
    };
    const handleClose = () => {
      setAnchorEl(null);
    };

  const columns: GridColDef[] = [
    { headerName: 'Name', field: 'name', flex: 1 },
    { headerName: 'Email', field: 'email', flex: 1 },
    { headerName: 'Date Added', field: 'added', flex: 0.7 },
    { headerName: 'Reports To', field: 'reports_to', flex: 1 },
    {
    field: ' ',
    flex: 0.2,
    renderCell: (params) => {
      return (
        <>
        <IconButton
          id="basic-button"
          aria-controls={open ? 'basic-menu' : undefined}
          aria-haspopup="true"
          aria-expanded={open ? 'true' : undefined}
          onClick={moreOptions}>
          <MoreIcon />
        </IconButton><Menu
          id="basic-menu"
          anchorEl={anchorEl}
          open={open}
          onClose={handleClose}
          MenuListProps={{
            'aria-labelledby': 'basic-button',
          }}
        >
            <MenuItem>
              <UserNotification />
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem onClick={() => { setShowEditModal(true); handleClose(); } }>
              <UserEdit />
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem onClick={() => { setShowDeleteModal(true); handleClose(); } }>
              <UserDelete />
            </MenuItem>
          </Menu>
          <EditUserModal userData={params.row} show={showEditModal} toggleModal={(value) => { setShowEditModal(value); } } />
          <DeleteUserModal userData={params.row} show={showDeleteModal} toggleModal={(value) => { setShowDeleteModal(value); } } />
          </>
      );
    } 
  },
  ];

return (
    <div style={{ height: 'auto', width: "100%" }}>
    <StripedDataGrid rows={userData} columns={columns} 
    getRowClassName={(params) =>
        params.indexRelativeToCurrentPage % 2 === 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'
      }
    hideFooter={true}
    autoHeight={true}
    components={{ Toolbar: GridToolbar }}
    />
    </div>
);
}
```

The Data Grid documentation does not have a clear guide on how to pass props of the grid forward. Attempting to populate userData instead of params gives me an overload error. What is the proper way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing with params.row always pointing to the last row is due to the closure in the renderCell function of the last column. Closures capture the variables by reference, so when the handleClose and moreOptions functions are called, they refer to the latest params object, which is the last row in the grid.

To fix this issue, you need to create a separate function that captures the correct params object for each row. You can use Function.prototype.bind or an arrow function to achieve this.

So move the codes below inside the renderCell function:

```js
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState<null | HTMLElement>(null);

  const [showEditModal, setShowEditModal] = React.useState<boolean>(false);
  const [showDeleteModal, setShowDeleteModal] = React.useState<boolean>(false);
  //for each modal

    const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
    const moreOptions = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
      setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
      
    };
    const handleClose = () => {
      setAnchorEl(null);
    };
```